# What are the different professions in TVA and what is the organisation structure like?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki-2021, time-variance-authority

In the *Loki* series in the TVA there people doing different tasks like some are judges, some are analysts, some are like policemen (Minutemen), some people have desk jobs. There are also people who do some other work like the person checking whether someone is a robot or not, or the person asking to sign the documents. I would like to know what are the different professions of people present in the TVA?

What is the organisation structure for TVA? Does it have different departments like in normal corporate company and a proper hierarchy as in a CEO followed by Directors, Managers, etc.

Comment: Time lord, time cop, time clock, time seasoning, time keeper, time new roman, time bandit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’ve pretty much covered the list really. So far the types of “jobs” we know of in the TVA are:

- **Judge:** the example of a judge we see is Ravonna Renslayer. Judges are the main leaders who control most of what goes on with a line to the “Time-Keepers”.
- **Agent:** the example of an agent we see is Mobius. Agents are those under a Judge who handle the more important cases.
- **Analyst:** Mobius is also an analyst and we see Analyst 1182-E as well. They seem to be more of a “techy” making sure everything looks right with the Sacred Timeline.
- **Hunter:** we see a few examples of hunters with Hunter B-15 and Hunter C-20 being the main ones. Hunters lead the missions to reset timelines and are the “squad leads” so to speak.
- **Minutemen:** these are the general soldiers that go out on the missions, we see lots of examples of these.
- **Clerk:** Casey is the prime example here, more of a general office staff type person: checking people in, filing records etc.
- **Librarian:** we see an unnamed, I believe, librarian working in the library, of course!

You might also count Miss Minutes and the Time-Keepers themselves. However,
As of episode 4

> The latter may not count anymore.

It’s unclear exactly what Miss Minutes is at this moment in time as well.